# Positioning a widget on another widget flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Positioning the widget like the image below:
(green over the red.)

[image: Here is the representation]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `Stack` with an `overflow` property of `Overflow.visible` and an `alignment` of `Alignemnt.center`, together with a `Positioned` widget with negative `bottom` value to achieve what you want. Here is a snippet I wrote for you, I tried to imitate the image you shared. You can run it [on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b) if you need to manipulate the parameters or explore further.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Stack(
          overflow: Overflow.visible,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 150,
              width: 300,
              color: Colors.red
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: -50,
              child: Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 150,
                color: Colors.green
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image: Result]